# Vuejs - Set "global" prop to edit all properties without using v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Assuming that I have this component below:

```
<c-attachs v-for="item in attachs" v-bind:path="item.path"></c-attachs>
```

And try to edit some property directly from some method, such as:

```
methods: {
    changeProp: function ()
    {
        this.path = 'myNewString';
    }
}
```

Vuejs warns on the console with the message:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders

But... if I set "v-bind:allprops="item" and edit property directly through "allprops" object (such as code below), it works fine without error. My doubt is... Is this the correct way to edit property on events without using v-model?

```
this.allprops.path = 'myNewString';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no correct way to edit props, because you are not supposed to edit them.

Every component should have complete control over its own `data`. That keeps behavior easy to reason about. Items that are passed to children as `props` should be considered read-only, so that the owner of those items retains control. That is why Vue has [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events).

When something happens in a component that should affect data that the component doesn't own, the component should [issue an event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event) so that the owner of the data item can handle it. If the owner of the data item changes its value, that change will flow down through the props.